# Private networks routing over IPSEC VPN

Tags: linux, vpn, routing, ipsec

I believe that this is actually pretty simple issue, but just cannot find out way to resolve it:

I have two site-to-site IPSEC VPN tunnels: Between sites A and B and between sites B and C

At site A:
- Private network is 192.168.10.0/24
- VPN server/client is Cisco's cabelmodel

At site B:
- Private network is 192.168.25.0/24
- VPN server/client is Racoon at top of Ubuntu

At site C:
- Private network is 192.168.40.0/24
- VPN server/client is Cisco's cabelmodel

I am able to reach site B from site A and from site C. If I login to "router machine" at site B's network, I can reach networks sites A and C.

At "vpn server" machine at 192.168.25.0 network (site A) I have IP-address 192.168.25.100 which I have defined in routing table as "gateway" from that machine to 192.168.10.0/24 and to 192.168.40.0/24 networks. That 192.168.25.100 address is reachable from 192.168.10.0 (site A) as well as from 192.168.40.0 (site C) networks.

The problem is here: Even I am able to reach 192.168.25.100 from networks of sites A and C, I am not able to reach network A from network C. I know that I could simply create new VPN tunnel directly to between Cisco modems at site A and C, but I want learn to make this with routing. I have tried add new route rule to machine at C site's network to route 192.168.10.0 via 192.168.25.100 to 192.168.40.0, but such route command not works. So what I am doing wrong and how to make it works?

I appreciate your time and help!

Answer (score 2):

Because of the lack of extra information about the defined policies for the IPsec tunnel i am just guessing here. But i've seen this issue several times and almost always people forgot to define policies to tunnel the traffic from A <=> C via B.

So simply said:

For the tunnel A <=>: B add a policy for the adresses 192.168.10.0/24 and 192.168.40.0/24 on both routers at site A and B

And for the tunnel C <=> B: add a policy for the adresses 192.168.40.0/24 and 192.168.10.0/24 on both routers at site B and C